# Anchor Database Modeling - is there anything better to store history and allow roll-back of the records?

Tags: database, database-design

I have red about anchor modelling from http://www.anchormodeling.com/ - there are a lot of publications that made sense to me. I am very concerned about the performance though... storing so many records in a property table and always working with the most recent one should drain memory and processor speed. The authors claim that this is not the case though.... Is there any better modelling technique to store history and allow roll-back of the records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally querying data in an Anchor modeled database falls within two categories:

1. OLTP-like queries, retrieving a large number of attributes using high selectivity conditions
2. OLAP-like queries, retrieving a small number of attributes using low selectivity conditions

In (1) the high selectivity, often constraining the results to that belonging to a single instance, will quickly pinpoint the desired instance followed by a small overhead due to the joins involved. The joins are however made on declared PK/FK relations on over tables already sorted by the single integer key corresponding to the identity of the instance. In other words, in a 6NF model (which is what provides the most temporal features), it is not possible to create a physical implementation that would perform better. As a case example, the Swedish insurance company [Länsförsäkringar](https://www.lansforsakringar.se/stockholm/privat/) has been running a real-time master data management system using Anchor since 2005, containing about 10 million engagements for 3 million customers, without performance issues. That being said, if extremely many queries are going to be run in parallel, the added overhead may become an issue.

In (2) since you are retrieving a small number of attributes the number of joins are reduced. In addition, the selectivity introduced by conditions make the joins behave like indexes (provided you have cost based optimizer that use column statistics). An optimal join order will be produced using the most selective condition first, so that intermediate result sets become as small as possible as early as possible with respect to the involved joins. As an additional benefit, the 6NF structure in Anchor maps directly onto distribution mechanisms in massively parallel processing relational databases, providing the best possible distribution for ad-hoc querying. As a case example, [avito.ru](https://www.avito.ru) has a 55TB data warehouse built using Anchor on a 12 node [Vertica](https://www.vertica.com) cluster, running without performance issues. In fact, this solution outperformed many of the other solutions they tested, including NoSQL alternatives.

As a conclusion, I would say that you cannot find a better modeling technique if you need to support temporality and flexibility. I have to point out though that I am one of the authors of the technique, although what I have said has been proven both in practice and theory, with scientific papers to back up the claims.

Comment: Does it matter if we use int as key or unique id data type. As that will be a clustered index in both cases my thinking is that it shouldn't, but can you confirm if that is what you have observed over many years of working with that database model. In my case I do not think to use the anchor model for all tables in my DB, but just for a small subset. Using it for all tables in 6NF will make the db to explode, I guess I will need to research for tools that can help me deal with that or just the development time will drastically increase.

Comment: Can you recommend tools that can transform a standard table into an anchor model table structure and will generate the necessary views and triggers and stored procedures?

Comment: I have only used integers as keys, but would expect performance to take a small hit due only to the fact that a uniqueidentifier is 16 bytes, compared to the 4 bytes of an int, effectively increasing the amount of data needed to be scanned during query execution.

Comment: I know there are tools that take a normalized schema and creates an Anchor model XML definition using intelligent guess work, but as far as I know none of them are available as Open Source. Nevertheless, I would expect there to always be anywhere from a little to quite a bit of hands on work on such a generated definition.